# how should I test the http response from a Cloudflare service using wrangler v3?

Tags: testing, cloudflare-workers

I have a Cloudflare service and would like to test its http responses. Best I can tell, I should be using wrangler v3's local workerd runtime. There is a [sample](https://github.com/cloudflare/workerd/tree/main/samples/unit-tests) but it is quite minimal so I have a few sub-questions:

**Q1**: Do I, somehow, run the service in one workerd nanoservice and run tests in other nanoservices? If so, how do I launch the service from the config.capnp?

**Q2**: The top of the config.capnp in the unit-tests sample suggests that it may be auto-generated at some point. Is this currently possible or advisable?

**Q3**: Should I use a service binding to send a fetch request from a test nanoservice to the service it is testing?

**Q4**: There is mention at https://blog.cloudflare.com/wrangler3/ that vitest integration is progressing. Is there an example of a test which exercises/exorcises a service?

Testing at this level is quite common and test-driven development places a focus on pre-emptive tests so I anticipate that examples and documentation are available. Regrettably, my search found a lot of information on Miniflare v2 but not for the latest Wrangler release and the workerd runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrangler exposes an `unstable_dev()` API which lets you programmatically spin-up Workers and send `fetch` requests to them, so you can assert the responses are as you expect with your preference of testing framework such as Vitest.

https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/wrangler/api/

For the available options you can pass to `unstable_dev()`, refer to [UnstableDevOptions](https://github.com/cloudflare/workers-sdk/blob/f7ae0ead2a48453845fcdbe3366b2db63d93b008/packages/wrangler/src/api/dev.ts#L12).

The Vitest integration you are referring to is the Miniflare environment, where you can access the KV/R2/etc bindings to assert that your Worker is interacting with those properly. That isn't back in Wrangler 3 at the time of writing, but is on the roadmap and will hopefully land in the coming months.

Comment: this [very recent test sample](https://github.com/smorimoto/cloudflare-workers-sdk-repro-3306) may be of interest to some. It is quite recent and manages to leverage vitest. The test in this sample does not pass due to a fault in the API being tested.

Comment: a [followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76844512/how-can-i-develop-a-cloudflare-worker-using-vitest-and-wrangler-v3)